# Global Autocomplete Search with Ransack gem and EasyAutoComplete (search query not working)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am at my wits end on this. I am trying to implement [this tutorial](https://gorails.com/episodes/global-autocomplete-search?autoplay=1) for a global autocomplete search bar which searches the database for keywords typed and lists them. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512084/searching-multiple-models-with-ransack-rails-4?rq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576663/how-to-fix-undefined-method-form-with-in-my-search-bar-when-building-out-globa), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284172/setting-default-search-parameter-on-ransack-for-rails?rq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351680/no-ransacksearch-object-was-provided-to-search-form-for), and several others. None has solved my issue.

The search query just does not return any results plus the autocomplete does not trigger. I, however, am still able to make calls to the function `easyAutocomplete` as shown in the [official guide](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide). And I have no errors (at least on the surface).

Here are my code samples:

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :photo_uploads

  #......................

  resources :posts do
    put 'publish' => 'posts#publish', on: :member
    put 'unpublish' => 'posts#unpublish', on: :member
  end
  get :search, controller: :posts
  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  get 'static_pages/about'

  get 'static_pages/contact'

end
```

**application_controller.rb:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :search


#.....................
  def search
    @q = Post.ransack(title_cont: params[:q])
    @searchpost= @q.result(distinct: true) 
    # @bodysearch = Post.ransack(body_cont: params[:q]).result(distinct: true) 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.json {
        @searchpost = @searchpost.limit(6) 
        # @bodysearch = @bodysearch.limit(6)
      }
    end 
  end
end
```

**erb file:**

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
    <%= f.search_field :title_cont, class: " search-bar ml-3", data: { behavior: "autocomplete" } %>
     <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**search.json.jbuilder:**

```
json.posts do
  json.array!(@posts) do |post|
    json.title post.title
    json.url post_path(post)
    json.published post.published_at
  end
end
```

**search.js:**

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  $input = $("[data-behaviour='autocomplete']")

  var options = {
    getValue: "title",
    url: function (phrase) {
      return "/search.json?q=" + phrase;

    },
    categories: [
      {
        listlocation: "posts",
        header: "<strong>Posts</strong>",
      }
    ],
    list: {
      onChooseEvent: function () {
        var url = $input.getSelectedItemData().url
        $input.val("")
        Turbolinks.visit(url)
      }
    }
  }
  $input.easyAutocomplete(options)
});
```

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
before_action :force_json, only: :search

# .............

private

    def force_json
      request.format = :json
    end
```

I use the devise gem for authentication and cancancan for user roles/access. They work just fine. The rails version is `5.1.6`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find what was wrong ? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Etienne
No, I did not. I had to shelve it and write the search queries manually. Not as perfect as I would have wanted, but what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but I was also trying to follow the tutorial and I had a similar issue. For me, I was using Rails 6 and webpacker and I had to make sure that the js and css files for easyautocomplete were in the asset pipeline and they were being linked properly. Then once I got webpacker to compile without errors, the search bar worked.

Comment: Could you please put the way you got that working in a post here?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

The reason was that Rails 6 significantly changed the Asset Pipeline, replacing the old way (Sprockets) with WebPacker + Yarn. So the JS parts in this tutorial no longer works.

Solution:
Combine that tutorial with this one:
https://joelc.io/dynamic-autocomplete-rails-6

In more details, here are the exact steps to get this to work:

1. Follow the GoRails tutorial to the end, see that it only works partially (the JS isn't triggered, but the standalone json page displays fine)
2. Keep the code, and follow the above-linked tutorial up until step 27. You can ignore the steps beyond that because the GoRails tutorial is better in that part